# Creating Sticky Nav with FadeIn and FadeOut Effects

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following code to create a sticky navigation menu. I'd like to fade this nav in as I scroll down the page (once it becomes "fixed"). I've tried opacity, adding and removing classes, but nothing seems to get me quite there...

```
function fixDiv() {
  var $cache = $('#menu-1'); 
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 150) 
    $cache.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'}).addClass("mega-fixed"); 
  else
    $cache.css({'position': 'relative', 'top': 'auto'}).removeClass("mega-fixed");

}
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
fixDiv();
```

I tried using an opacity element within the css above, with a "transition: all 1s" effect applied to the added class of "mega-fixed." When I scroll down the page the effect is an elegant fade in sticky navigation. However, when scrolling back up the page, the navigation disappears. I can tell why this is happening via the code, but I can't correct it...

Answer (score 0):

Was able to achieve this with jQuery Waypoints and the following code:

```
$('body').waypoint(function() {
        $('#megamenu-1').addClass('mega-fixed').css({
            'display' : 'none'
        }).fadeIn(100);
        $('.mega-fixed').fadeOut(100);
        $('.mega-fixed').removeClass('mega-fixed').fadeIn(100);

}, {offset: -40 });
```